# PySpark - converting hour and minute data to seconds

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have a given time of XXh:YYm (ex 1h:23m) that I'm trying to convert to seconds. The tricky part is that if it is less than an hour then the time will be given as just YYm (eg 52m).

I am currently using

```
%pyspark
newColumn = unix_timestamp(col("time"), "H:mm")

dataF.withColumn('time', regexp_replace('time', 'h|m', '')).withColumn("time", newColumn).show()
```

This works great for removing the h and m letters and then converting to seconds, but throws a null when the time is less than an hour as explained above since it's not actually on the H:mm format. What's a good approach to this? I keep trying different things that seems to overcomplicate it, and I still haven't found a solution.

I am leaning toward some sort of conditional like

```
if value contains 'h:' then newColumn = unix_timestamp(col("time"), "H:mm")
else  newColumn = unix_timestamp(col("time"), "mm")
```

but I am fairly new to pyspark and not sure how to do this to get the final output. I am basically looking for an approach that will convert a time to seconds and can handle formats of '1h:23m' as well as '53m'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, assuming time column is stringtype. Just used when otherwise to separate the two different  times(by contains 'h') and used substring to get desired minutes.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("seconds", F.when(F.col("time").contains("h"), F.unix_timestamp(F.regexp_replace("time", "h|m", ''),"H:mm"))\
.otherwise(F.unix_timestamp(F.substring("time",1,2),"mm")))\
.show()

+------+-------+
|  time|seconds|
+------+-------+
|1h:23m|   4980|
|   23m|   1380|
+------+-------+
```

Comment: Can someone show how to do the opposite? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**unix_timestamp**" function to convert DateTime to unix timestamp in seconds.

You can refer to one of my blog on the Spark DateTime function and go to "**unix_timestamp**" section.

https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/deep-dive-into-apache-spark-datetime-functions-b66de737950a

Regards,

Neeraj